# Where did 'Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page' come from?

Tags: grails, spring-security, authorization, grails-plugin

I am using spring security plugin for Grails. I can get LDAP authenticated and see authorization working as well. When authorization failed, I can see 'Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page'. Where did this error come from?

My SecureController code is the following.

```
package com.testapp

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder

class SecureController {


   @Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
   def showUser()  {
        def msg = ' ROLE_USER users see this'

        render view: 'enter', model: [msg: msg]
   }

   @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
   def showAdmin() {
      def msg = ' ROLE_ADMIN users see this'
      render view: 'enter', model: [msg: msg]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That page is the [denied.gsp](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/views/login/denied.gsp) view/page from within the Spring security core plugin. This view is shown when access to the requested resource is denied (e.g. fails `@Secured` check).

If you want to replace it with your own view, create a new view/page `grails-app/views/login/denied.gsp`.

Comment: Thanks Yes. Most likely I will have a customized denied.gsp.

Comment: **denied.gsp** seems moved out by now & gives 404, Anyway,  You can access the main denied.gsp @  [link](https://github.com/grails/grails-spring-security-core/tree/5.0.x/plugin/grails-app/views/login)